# How to add base permalink to custom posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I am having a hard time understanding how custom posts work. I want to achieve the following:

```
Post:
/blog360/2015/07/25/hello-world
/blog360/category/programming
/blog360/tag/wordpress
/blog360/page/2, /blog360/tag/wordpress/page/2, /blog360/category/programming/page/2

Custom Post: Portfolio
/portfolio/work-name-here
/portfolio/category/programming
/portfolio/tag/wordpress
/portfolio/page/2
/portfolio/category/programming/page/2
/portfolio/tag/wordpress/page/2
```

So, first I added the tag and category base form **Settings > Permalinks**:

```
Category Base: blog360/category
Tag Base: blog360/tag
```

This fixed the Post issue not prepending blog360. Even though I don't like it; I wish the base text was selected based on the selected posts page slug but that's not my main concern right now. Then I created a custom post "portfolio" and

```
/portfolio/work-name-here
```

also worked. But I can't get custom taxonomy to work. Here is my code:

```
function __add_custom_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $labels, $hierarchial = false, $rewrite = true) {
    $args = [
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchial' => $hierarchial,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => $rewrite,
        'sort' => true
    ];

    register_taxonomy($name, $post_type, $args);
}

__add_custom_taxonomy('portfolio-category', 'portfolio', $category_labels, true, ['slug' => 'portfolio/category']);
__add_custom_taxonomy('portfolio-tag', 'portfolio', $tag_labels, false, ['slug' => 'portfolio/tag']);
```

When I go try to give /portfolio/category/programming, it gives me 404. Same with tags. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: I assume those calls are hooked to `init`? Did you flush rewrite rules after? Do the categories/tags have posts assigned to them? When multiple objects share the same slug, the order you register things in can matter, as that affects rewrite rule hierarchy. [This rewrite analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) may shed some light on what's wrong.

Comment: My categories and tags are loaded after the custom post is loaded and I can see the problem now. How can I force loading taxonomy rewrite rules before custom post rewrite rules?